# Sum the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ if $a_n =(-1)^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{m}\rfloor}} \cdot r^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

> Let $0<r<1$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Sum the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$$ if $a_n =(-1)^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{m}\rfloor}} \cdot r^{n}$

I get stuck here because I don't know how to deal with the floor function here. Can someone give me hints on how to deal with that floor function?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $a_n=(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{m}\rfloor}r^n$?

Comment: Oh, you are right. I just edit it.

Comment: Did you try to compute the partial sum from $n=km$ to $n=(k+1)m-1$? Then you should...

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\rfloor= k,\quad\forall km\leq n<(k+1)m.$$
Then compute
$$\sum_{n=km}^{(k+1)m-1}(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{m}\rfloor}r^n=\sum_{n=km}^{(k+1)m-1}(-1)^kr^n=(-1)^kr^{km}\frac{1-r^m}{1-r}.$$
Thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=km}^{(k+1)m-1}a_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kr^{km}\frac{1-r^m}{1-r}=\frac{1-r^m}{1-r}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-r^m)^k=\frac{1-r^m}{(1-r)(1+r^m)}.$$